# Running OS image from Dell Laptop (set to RAID mode) in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, raid, ahci, intel-rst

I have two SSD images from two different modern Dell laptops that use the new BIOS that allows you to set your boot mode to "legacy" and then set your SATA mode to AHCI or "Raid mode" (Intel Rapid Storage Technology). These laptops were set to legacy boot and RAID mode to allow Windows 7 to run on them.

Now, these SSD images cannot run when restored to computers that only have AHCI mode. Windows 7 appears to boot correctly and it spends a few seconds on the logo-loading screen and then it goes straight to a blue screen with a STOP 0x0000007b error. The same thing happens in the original laptops if the SATA mode is changed from RAID to AHCI.

I need to run these images in VirtualBox but I get the same BSOD. My question is: Is there something I can change on either VirtualBox or the restored image itself that may allow Windows to succesfully complete the startup process?

I've tried setting VirtualBox to use all different controller options (IDE with its different chipsets, SATA, SCSI and SaS) with no success.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or comments.

Comment: Sysprep the images before trying to move/boot them on different hardware (the VM).

Comment: @techie007: Can you please elaborate a Little bit more or point me in the right direction? These images where made with "R Drive Image" and I no longer have one of the laptops in question just the image.

Comment: Then unfortunately you're probably screwed.  You can't just move Windows around willy-nilly between hard drive controllers - the drivers for the controller have to be in the OS before it can use them.  Since you're coming from a RAID mode, it's even more important.  Basically you did it wrong in the first place, and you're now stuck. :(  For future reference: [Sysprep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysprep).  Maybe someone will have a magic answer, but I doubt it if you can't even read the data on the disks.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different things, including several registry key changes (via load hive from another Windows install, since I cannot boot this one), the only and great solution I found was to use **Paragon Adaptive Recovery**. I followed [this small tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/292068-make-windows-7-bootable-after-motherboard-swap.html).

I gotta say this was way better tan sysprep and other things I tried. Windows stayed **in** the domain it had joined before (which was not posible with other solutions) and all domain related stuff was kept properly. I even was able to reactivate Windows, Office and other software through the corporate licencing server.

I hope this helps more people in the future. Great tool. :-)